# Excel 2007 plot with labeled data items

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, charts

I have data in the following format, where each label defines a row of data:

```
label1   x1 y1

label1   x2 y2

label1   x3 y3

label2   x1 y1

label2   x2 y2

label2   x3 y3
```

This is a very large data set, so selecting each range and adding it to the plot is out. Is there any way to plot it?

Comment: Found something similar here: http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/343380.html

Comment: Does each cell actually contain _"x"_ and _"y"_? Or are there column headings?

Comment: perhaps I should have used values instead. Each cell labeled x*, y* contains a numeric value

Comment: I'd recommend you consider removing the _"x"_ or _"y"_ in each cell and add headings. It will make it a lot easier to use the data the way you like.

Answer (score 0):

This known Excel Add-In has that functionality http://www.andrewsexceltips.net/JMT%20Full%20List.htm

It has a Ribbon so its esy to use in Excel 2007+